# Removing for loops and appending to lists in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, optimization

I need to optimize my code and have been able to remove for loops almost everywhere but struggle for this small part. I've looked at numpy.where but don't think I can use that but I'm not quite sure. If anyone knows which functions I should look at to optimize this part that would be greatly appreciated. This is used quite often and for loops are very slow in pyton so i need to do some optimization.

```
def f(x):
    return np.pi * x * np.cos((np.pi / 2) * x ** 2)

x_samples = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=500000)
y_samples = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=500000) * 1.61
y_functie = f(x_samples)
y_hit, x_hit, x_miss, y_miss = [], [], [], []
for n in range(len(x_samples)):
    if y_samples[n] <= y_functie[n]:
        x_hit.append(x_samples[n]), y_hit.append(y_samples[n])
    else:
        x_miss.append(x_samples[n]), y_miss.append(y_samples[n])
```

Comment: Show the values(dummy if not Real) of variables used in above code

Comment: You could use `enumerate` instead of `range(len(x_samples))` but beyond that I don't see how removing the loop will help you. Any list comprehension or other method of building these lists will also be looping through them.

Comment: You could stack `y_samples` and `x_samples` and do array indexing with fancy slicing but I think your implementation so far is quite good.

Comment: @Sociopath I added how the data looks. Something i'd be needing would be something like np.where but instead of adding something when the condition is true and something else when the condition is false, I'd need to have the true and false variables in different lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing indexing you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
return np.pi * x * np.cos((np.pi / 2) * x ** 2)

x_samples = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=500000)
y_samples = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=500000) * 1.61

y_functie = f(x_samples)

def test1():
    y_hit, x_hit, x_miss, y_miss = [], [], [], []
    for n in range(len(x_samples)):
        if y_samples[n] <= y_functie[n]:
            x_hit.append(x_samples[n]), y_hit.append(y_samples[n])
        else:
            x_miss.append(x_samples[n]), y_miss.append(y_samples[n])

def test2():
    x_hit = x_samples[y_samples<=y_functie]
    x_miss = x_samples[y_samples>y_functie]
    y_hit = y_samples[y_samples<=y_functie]
    y_miss = y_samples[y_samples>y_functie]
    
test1()
test2()
```

With your test data I get timing differences of 700ms for `test1` and 21ms for `test2`. Of course you could simplify more by using only one boolean table and do everything in one go.

Depending on what you want to optimize for (speed or memory footprint) you could precalculate the boolean table with

```
hit_test = y_samples<=y_functie
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical masking with the `fancy indexing` to achieve the desired outcome:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return np.pi * x * np.cos((np.pi / 2) * x ** 2)

x_samples = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=500000)
y_samples = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=500000) * 1.61

y_functie = f(x_samples)

hits = y_samples <= y_functie
misses = y_samples > y_functie

y_hit, x_hit, x_miss, y_miss = x_samples[hits], y_samples[hits], x_samples[misses], y_samples[misses]
```

Cheers.